# How can remove the LVM in my os?

Tags: lvm

List LVM in my os with uuid value:

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sdc1: UUID="55aaf5c1-acd2-4bb2-9536-f2900c96d6b2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="debian11" PARTUUID="429028f9-912c-4287-8888-9c5c2a7ff95e"
/dev/sdc2: UUID="ff51b0dd-6a25-4e78-8da1-83f4aef761e1" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="696f5180-48db-4b4c-bc01-d01b43dc5bd5"
/dev/sdc3: UUID="A1F6-EF8C" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="4ced8eca-eca3-43a1-958d-369c9e34b237"
/dev/sdc4: UUID="25b25a1a-3874-434f-8320-0004868a1b96" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c145cb1d-40bf-4acd-891d-8c0ac4838d30"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="QyJQim-npa9-17Tn-juTr-4BAy-bS6j-e3lGTO" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="c6fd205e-398b-4774-87e0-09dc846eb4c0"
```

I have never install my os with LVM,don't remenber how to create it.
How can remove it then?

Comment: delete the partition using `fdisk` or `gdisk` or even `parted /dev/sdc rm 5`

Comment: Before you delete it, check with `lvs` that you're not unexpectedly using the volume group

Comment: What OS (or Linux distribution) are you using? What does `lvs` report? What does `df -h` report?

Comment: Os installed in /dev/sda,i removed the /dev/sdc5,reboot,nothing happens,ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the partition using `fdisk` or `gdisk` or even `parted /dev/sdc rm`.

However before you do that use `lvs` to ensure there are no unexpected logical volumes in the position you're about to delete